# How can i compute the code as percentage?

Tags: r

```
scoresQA<-t(apply(FormA[-1,-1],1,function (x) as.numeric((FormA[1,-1]==x))))
scoresPerQA<-apply(scoresQA,2,sum)

scoresQB<-t(apply(FormB[-1,-1],1,function (x) as.numeric((FormB[1,-1]==x))))
scoresPerQB<-apply(scoresQB,2,sum)
```

This is the code that i made to determine the overall score for each question. How can i compute this as a percentage?(to nnn.n%format)

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know how FormA and FormB looks like. However, maybe this already does the trick:

```
scoresQA <- t(apply(FormA[-1,-1], 1, function (x) as.numeric((FormA[1,-1]==x))))
scoresPerQA <- apply(scoresQA, 2, sum)
QA_percentage <- scoresPerQA / nrow(scoresQA)

scoresQB <- t(apply(FormB[-1,-1], 1, function (x) as.numeric((FormB[1,-1]==x))))
scoresPerQB <- apply(scoresQB, 2, sum)
QB_percentage <- scoresPerQB / nrow(scoresQB)
```